# Regex to match KB file names

Tags: regex, windows, powershell

So I have a regex that I'm using with powershell to look for Microsoft kb files.  It does a pretty good job, but I'm trying to implement a sort of `or` check as well.

The file names typically look like this:

```
blahblah-kb123456-x86.exe
blahblah-kb1234567-x86.exe
blahblah-kb123456-v2-x86.exe
blahblah-kb1234567-v2-x86.exe
```

My regex looks like this:

`'^.+\-[kK][bB][0-9]{6,7}\-{0,1}[vV]{0,1}[0-9]{0,1}\-[xX][0-9]+.exe'`

This doesn't match the above conditions consistently.  Any ideas on how I can improve it?

Comment: As it stands, your regex does not match *any* of the sample names.

Comment: @Tomalak sorry it does... I just forgot to show that the names could have other information before it

Comment: I figured that already. Regex questions need to be particularly precise, though.

Comment: As it now stands, your regex matches *all* of the sample names. ;-)

Comment: Powershell regex by default is case insensitive, so this is the same, but as @Tomalak, your regex matches all of the examples. ^.+\-kb\d{6,7}-?v?\d?-x\d+.exe

Comment: hmm... let me go back to my code and see what's happening..  thanks guys

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're making a few minor general mistakes.

- The `-` does not need to be escaped.
- `{0,1}` is a verbose way of saying `?`.
- Optional sub-patterns need to be in parentheses to make then atomic.
- You can use a case-insensitive flag instead of specifying every letter like `[kK]`.
- You *could* say `[0-9]{6,7}`, but do you know that there will never be a KB number longer than 7 digits? Better is `[0-9]{6,}`.
- You say `.exe` but you mean `\.exe`.
- I think you want a `$` at the end.

Applying this to your expression, you get

```
^.+-kb[0-9]{6,}-(?:v[0-9]+-)?x[0-9]+\.exe$
```

which breaks down as

```
^              # start-of-string
.+             # anything, at least one character
-              # a "-"
kb[0-9]{6,}    # "kb" and at least 6 digits
-              # a "-"
(?:            # start of non-capturing group
  v[0-9]+      #   "v" and some digits
  -            #   a "-"
)?             # end of group, make optional
x[0-9]+        # "x" and some digits
\.exe          # ".exe"
$              # end-of-string
```

To make regular expression case-insensitive in-line, use `(?i)` (that's a feature of .NET regular expression engine, but supported by other engines as well).

```
(?i)^.+-kb[0-9]{6,}-(?:v[0-9]+-)?x[0-9]+\.exe$
```

http://rubular.com/r/Lj1Vm1XYkt

Comment: Your second point talks about `{0,1}` being a verbose way of saying `?`, but how do you specify the `n` number of matches using this syntax?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. `{0,1}` means *"zero occurrences or exactly one occurrence"*, which is what `?` means - it's a shorthand for the same thing. There is no `n` involved here.